# What languages can be compiled to WebAssembly (Wasm)?

Tags: llvm, programming-languages, webassembly

What languages can be compiled to WebAssembly (Wasm)?

I believe right now C, C++, and Rust (experimental) can be compiled to WebAssembly, with the llvm compiler backend, with languages like Java, Swift, and C# not currently being supported, but being possible candidates for future development.

I don't believe JavaScript can be compiled to Wasm.
https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/issues/219

Comment: Just as a note to anyone reading this, I've recently used C and C++ to WASM via emscripten and it works very nicely.

Answer (score 164):

WebAssembly support is ever evolving. Right now it is supported by the following languages:

- **C / C++** - has very good (production ready) support via [EmScripten](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/), or other [minimal LLVM-based toolchains](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webassembly)
- **Rust** - WebAssembly is an officially supported target, with a [highly active community](https://github.com/rustwasm) around it.
- **Go** - has [now supports WebAssembly](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/WebAssembly) as an official, yet experimental, target
- **C#** - has experimental support via [Blazor](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/Blazor), however this currently requires embedding a .NET runtime into Wasm. Blazor was officially adopted by Microsoft as an experimental technology, with a [recent preview release](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/03/22/get-started-building-net-web-apps-in-the-browser-with-blazor/).
- **D** - the "betterC" subset of D can be compiled to WebAssembly [through LDC](https://wiki.dlang.org/Generating_WebAssembly_with_LDC) (LLVM compiler).
- **TypeScript** - via [AssemblyScript](http://assemblyscript.org/), highly experimental, but gaining momentum.
- **Java** - via [TeaVM](http://teavm.org/) or [Bytecoder](https://github.com/mirkosertic/Bytecoder)
- **Haxe** - [just announced support](https://github.com/ncannasse/webidl)
- **Kotlin** - using official [Kotlin/Wasm](https://kotl.in/wasm) compiler and via [TeaVM](http://teavm.org/)
- **Python** - [Pyodide](https://github.com/iodide-project/pyodide) is a port of Python to WebAssembly that includes the core packages of the scientific Python stack (Numpy, Pandas, matplotlib).
- **PHP** - Experimental, but with a [working prototype](https://github.com/oraoto/pib)
- **Perl** - [WebPerl](https://webperl.zero-g.net/) is a port of the Perl binary to WebAssembly, allowing you to run Perl scripts on the web.
- **Scala** - using the [Emscripten compiler](https://github.com/shadaj/scala-native-wasm), and [TeaVM](http://teavm.org/)
- **Ruby** - via the [run.rb](https://runrb.io/) project
- **Swift** - using [SwiftWasm](https://swiftwasm.org/)

There are commercial solutions also:

- **RemObjects** - Which has [announced support for C#, Java, Swift and Oxygene](https://blogs.remobjects.com/2018/01/12/webassembly-swift-c-java-and-oxygene-in-the-browser/)

Regarding JavaScript, it is unlikely to gain support as WebAssembly is a statically typed assembly language.

There are also various more obscure / hobbyist languages that support WebAssembly. Further details can be found on the more exhaustive [Awesome WebAssembly Languages](https://github.com/appcypher/awesome-wasm-langs) list.

Comment: Commercial C#/Java/Swift implementations: https://blogs.remobjects.com/2018/01/12/webassembly-swift-c-java-and-oxygene-in-the-browser/ . Also: https://github.com/appcypher/awesome-wasm-langs

Comment: Good point - I've added RemObjects as a category of it's own as it is multi-language and commercial

Comment: But Python is dynamically typed!

Comment: it's strongly typed

Comment: there is new project on github which allows to compile TypeScript to WASM - (TypeScript Native Compiler) https://github.com/ASDAlexander77/TypeScriptCompiler

Answer (score 20):

See https://github.com/mbasso/awesome-wasm#compilers -- for now it's only C/C++, others are experimental, but amount of the "experimental" part grows.

Currently WebAssembly supports just flat linear memory. That's suitable for C/C++/Rust and a lot of other languages, but most popular modern languages need garbage collector to run. That's "post-MVP feature" of WebAssembly (see https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/issues/1079). For now the only option is to implement garbage collector inside the wasm with some custom code.

Comment: It is worth adding that asm.js can be easily compiled to wasm and asm.js _is_ javascript. That said, compiling javascript is/would be much more difficult because it generally lacks as much immediately available contextual information.

Answer (score 18):

## [This repo](https://github.com/appcypher/awesome-wasm-langs)

Contains a list of languages that currently compile to or have their VMs in WebAssembly(wasm)

### Features:

- Uses emojis to show how mature each language is currently
- Provides links to each languages project names and options

Comment: "Uses emojis to show how mature each language is currently" read that one to yourself a couple of times ...it's a pretty deep statement.

Comment: Yup, simple intuitive explanations coupled with silly expressions.

Comment:  - Work in progress.
 - Unstable but usable.
 - Stable for production usage.

Answer (score 12):

TeaVM can be used to transpile JVM bytecode to WebAssembly. You can checkout the project homepage at https://github.com/konsoletyper/teavm.

TeaVM at its core can transpile JVM bytecode to JS and WebAssembly. WebAssembly support is in an early stage, but there are demos available to compare performance of a simple JBox2D simulation with GWT, TeaVM(JS output) and TeaVM(WASM output), which are quite impressive.

Please note that WebAssembly currently has no direct access to the DOM or other JavaScript APIs. Also in the current MVP there is no support for opaque datatypes or even the GC. However, it is possible to do up/downcalls from JS to WASM and back again using some JS trickery, as seen in the mentioned demos.